# Table Row attr() Issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm stuck on a piece of code that calls a jQuery modul populated with a table row `id`.  I'm about 90% sure that the error is within my jQuery code.  Once I click on the button (class="view"), I get an undefined value instead of the row `ID`.

Thanks for any help!

Relevant section of leads_queue_a.php:

```
<section class="main">
     <h1>Lead Queue - Assigned Leads</h1>
     <div id="lead_wrapper_a"></div>
</section>
```

fill_leads_a.php:

```
$cond = array();
$params = array();

if ($_POST['id'] == '') {
    return;
}

if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != '') {
    $userID = $_POST['id'];
}
if (!empty($userID)) {
    $cond[] = '`users`.`id` = ?';
    $params[] = "$userID";
}

$query = "SELECT `leads`.`id`, `leads`.`fname`, `leads`.`lname`, `leads`.`lead_type`, `leads`.`addr_street`, `leads`.`addr_city`, `leads`.`addr_zip`, `leads`.`phone`, `leads`.`phone_alt`, `leads`.`note`, `leads`.`created_by`, `leads`.`created` FROM `leads`,`users`,`leads_assignment`";

if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$query .= ' AND `leads`.`id` = `leads_assignment`.`id_lead`'
        . ' AND `users`.`id` = `leads_assignment`.`id_user`';


$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

//TABLE BUILDER
$lead = '';
$lead .= '<div class="leads">';
$lead .= '<table class="lead_table">';
$lead .= '<tr>';
$lead .= '<td>Customer</td>';
$lead .= '<td>Phone</td>';
$lead .= '<td>Lead Type</td>';
$lead .= '<td>Status</td>';
$lead .= '<td>Operations</td>';
$lead .= '</tr>';

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
    $id = $row->id;
    $status = get_statusLast($id);
    $fname = $row->fname;
    $lname = $row->lname;
    $lead_type = $row->lead_type;
    $addr_street = $row->addr_street;
    $addr_city = $row->addr_city;
    $addr_zip = $row->addr_zip;
    $phone = $row->phone;
    $phone_alt = $row->phone_alt;
    $note = $row->note;
    $created_by = $row->created_by;
    $created = $row->created;

    $lead .= "<tr id='$id'>";
    $lead .= '<td>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br />' . $addr_street . '<br />' . $addr_city . ' ' . $addr_zip . '</td>';
    $lead .= '<td>' . $phone . '<br />' . $phone_alt . '</td>';
    $lead .= '<td>' . $lead_type . '</td>';
    $lead .= '<td>' . $status . '</td>';
    $lead .= '<td><button type="button" class="view" name="view">View Notes</button><br />'
            . '<button type="button" class="update" name="update">Update Status</button></td>';
}
$lead .= '</table>';
$lead .= '</div>';
$db = null;
print $lead;
```

Relevent section of modul.js:

```
$("#lead_wrapper_a").on('click', '.view', function() {
      alert($('tr', this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your selction is incorrect. Use **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get to the clicked buttons parent row (tr). Using the syntax `$('tr', this)` you are trying to find `tr` that are descendant of the button `.view` which is incorrect. You need to go upwards to get to the `tr`. `this` in the handler will be the `button`.

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
```

Comment: That's it!  It seems like every time I ask a question on StackOverflow, I end up having to wait 10 minutes to accept the answers ;)  You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to search row `tr` in descendant of `button` but `button` is descendant of row `tr`. You probably need `closest()` to get the *ancestor* row, to get the parent row of button having class `view`.

```
$("#lead_wrapper_a").on('click', '.view', function() {
      alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant find `tr` within the context of `this`, Because tr is the ancestor of the source button in your case. So you have to use `.closest()` to achieve the desired result.

Try,

```
$("#lead_wrapper_a").on('click', '.view', function() {
      $( "#dialog_view" ).dialog( "open" );
      alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to table its bit tricky.

for your first line you want to select the entire path of class "view".   I dont know your exact path but it should be someting like this.

$("#lead_wrapper_a").on('click', '"#lead_wrapper_a > table > tbody > tr > td.view', function() {

});

Hope this helps